# Is this a routing error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

```
get 'androids/customer', to: 'androids#customer'
get 'androids/:id', to: 'androids#customerview'
get 'androids', to: 'androids#items'
get 'androids/new', to: 'androids#new'
post 'androids/create', to: 'androids#create'
get '/androids/:id', to: 'androids#show'
get 'androids/:id/edit', to: 'androids#edit'
patch 'androids/:id/update', to: 'androids#update'
get 'androids/:id/delete', to: 'androids#delete'
get 'androids/:id/sold', to: 'androids#show'
```

class AndroidsController < ApplicationController

```
def items
    @android = Android.all 
end

def customer
    @android = Android.all
end

def customerview
    @android = Android.find(params[:id])
end

def show
    @android = Android.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @android = Android.new
end


def create
    @android = Android.new
    @android.name = params[:android][:name]
    @android.brand = params[:android][:brand]
    @android.year = params[:android][:year]
    @android.camera = params[:android][:camera]
    @android.mpixel = params[:android][:mpixel]
    @android.storage = params[:android][:storage]
    @android.slot = params[:android][:slot]
    @android.size = params[:android][:size]
    @android.os = params[:android][:os]
    @android.stock = params[:android][:stock]
    @android.save
    redirect_to "/androids/#{@android.id}"
end

def edit
    @android = Android.find(params[:id])
end

def delete 
    @android = Android.find(params[:id])
    @android.destroy
    redirect_to '/androids'
end

def update
    @android = Android.find(params[:id])
    @android.update_attributes(android_params)
    redirect_to "/androids/#{@android.id}"
end


private
def android_params
    params.require(:android).permit(:name, :brand, :year, :camera, :mpixel, :storage, :slot, :size, :os, :stock)
end
```

end

When I access 'androids/:id' it shows the #androids#show not the #androids#customerview. Is there something wrong with my code? What should I do with this routing error? When I manually type localhost:****/androids/customer/2 it shows the right html page, however when I click the link from the customers page it directs me to the /android/:id page only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have duplicate definitions of /androids/:id in your routes.

Here are the updated routes:

```
get 'androids/customer', to: 'androids#customer'
get 'androids', to: 'androids#items'
get 'androids/new', to: 'androids#new'
post 'androids/create', to: 'androids#create'
get 'androids/:id', to: 'androids#customerview'
get 'androids/:id/edit', to: 'androids#edit'
patch 'androids/:id/update', to: 'androids#update'
get 'androids/:id/delete', to: 'androids#delete'
get 'androids/:id/sold', to: 'androids#show'
```

A couple of notes:

- You should strongly consider using resource-based routes, which are much easier to manage
- any route with :id params (or any replaceable params) should go after the fixed-name routes

Comment: Thanks it worked for the customer view! Can't I use it twice?

Comment: The second time you use the same route declaration, the first gets overwritten.  In your example, the `to: 'androids#show'` replaced the previous controller action (`'androids#customerview'`), so all accesses to `/androids/:id` were reassigned to always direct to the `'androids#show'` action.